# why swift think its optional let input = int(a)

Tags: swift

I have following simple code after last line sum swift gives error
and var sum=input*2 should be changed to var sum=input!*2

I am not sure why since i didn't  declare variable a as optional.
Does swift make input as optional ?  Thanks

```
Var a="2"
let input = int(a)
var sum=input*2
```

Comment: Thank you everyone for your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Casting a string to an int returns and Optional because it could fail.

For example, `let result = Int("foo")` will return nil, because "foo" is not a valid Int.

Answer (score 2):

What if you did

```
Var a = "This is most defiantly not a number and even if it were its too long to fit within an int 123457993849038409238490ff9f-09-0f9-09f dd0d0066646464646464349023849038490328 I'm a teapot". 
let input = int(a)
```

Do you think that could be converted to an int? Now do you understand why its an optional?

Answer (score 1):

What happens if the String can't be converted to an Int? Such as Int("A"). It becomes an optional because the compiler can't know for sure that the String you are passing in can become an Int.

```
 guard let intVal = Int(a) else { return }
```

or

```
 if let intVal = Int(a) {
 //you have a valid Int here
 }
```

is the way to go about handling this situation